# systemd support for toggling mutually exclusive services?

Tags: systemd

I have two versions of a service that I occasionally want to switch between - my-service-a and my-service-b. I want my-service-a to always be the one which is running when the system is booted. Currently, to switch between them, I have to run multiple commands, e.g. to switch from a to b

```
systemctl stop my-service-a
systemctl start my-service-b
```

and there is no enforcement by systemd that only one is running at a time - I just have to be careful.

Is there any direct support for this situation in systemd? I could see it being either support for "toggling" between services, or instantiations of a templated service, or I could see it as support for mutually-exclusive services, so that when I start my-service-b, my-service-a is automatically stopped. Or maybe there is another way entirely.

Comment: Try [Conflicts=](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `Conflicts=` directive to the `[Unit]` section of your two unit files (`Conflicts=` in just one unit file works, too).  From the man page for [systemd.unit(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=):

> A space-separated list of unit names. Configures negative requirement
>   dependencies. If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit,
>   starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa. Note that
>   this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the After= and
>   Before= ordering dependencies.